# Replace a Cisco VPN IPSec concentrator with an Ubuntu-box

Tags: cisco, cisco-vpn, site-to-site-vpn, openswan

Is it possible to replace a Cisco VPN IPSec concentrator with Ubuntu and for instance Strongswan?

1) Do Strongswan implement the same protocolls that Cisco uses?

2) Can we retrieve keys from the Cisco concentrator and import them to the Ubuntu-box, if not can we generate new keys that suits equipment at sites?

3) Are there any performance concerns to think of?

Comment: Of course it's possible. It may or may not be a good idea in your particular case, but I downvoted your question because it is the type of question you shouldn't ask here ( http://serverfault.com/faq#dontask )

Comment: How would I rephrace the question? We have a Cisco concentrator that I have to replace. We have a bunch of users using our services thru this infrastructure today that we will take responsibility for from another company. The Cisco equipment except at clients sites in three continents, belongs to the other company.  I want to replace this device without changeing any configurations at the clients sites or as little as possible. We run a small Ubuntu server datacenter and use Ubuntu for most of our services and other routing, firewalling purposes.

Comment: The people we have contact with does not know what protocol they are using besides its VPN.

Comment: To make a better question, read and understand the documentation. Then, pose specific questions for any issues that you run into or think you might run into.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can find examples of remote-access VPN and site-to-site VPN configuration for Strongswan listed [here](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv2Examples) helpful.